# Controller method not found on postEdit()

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-4

I'm getting a weird error `NotFoundHttpException Controller method not found.` even though I am sure it exists. My routes are very simple and I think `artisan routes` checks out. But I keep receiving this error it's frustrating.

The error appears when I click the submit button on the edit page.

This is `routes.php`

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
Route::controller('listings', 'ListingsController');
Route::get('contacts', function()
{
    return View::make('listings.add');
});
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

This is `postEdit()` method in `ListingsController.php`

```
public function postEdit($id)
    {
    // validate
    // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
    $rules = array(
            'status'       => 'required',
            'listingfor'      => 'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('listings/edit/' . $id)
                    ->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        $listings = Listing::find($id);
        $listings->status = Input::get('status');
        $listings->listingfor = Input::get('listingfor');
        $listings->propertystatus = Input::get('propertystatus');
        $listings->propertytype = Input::get('propertytype');
        $listings->userid = Auth::user()->id;
        $listings->reference_id = Input::get('reference_id');
        $listings->location = Input::get('location');
        $listings->lifestyle = Input::get('lifestyle');
        $listings->category = Input::get('category');
        $listings->apartment_area = Input::get('apartment_area');
        $listings->garden_area = Input::get('garden_area');
        $listings->parking = Input::get('parking');
        $listings->visitors_parking = Input::get('visitors_parking');
        $listings->driver_room = Input::get('driver_room');
        $listings->furnished = Input::get('furnished');
        $listings->salons = Input::get('salons');
        $listings->family_room = Input::get('family_room');
        $listings->master_bedrooms = Input::get('master_bedrooms');
        $listings->balconies = Input::get('balconies');
        $listings->standard_bedrooms = Input::get('standard_bedrooms');
        $listings->maid_room = Input::get('maid_room');
        $listings->dining_room = Input::get('dining_room');
        $listings->bathrooms = Input::get('bathrooms');
        $listings->contact_id = $contact_id;
        $listings->save();

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated Listing!');
        $this->layout->content = Redirect::to('listings/main');
            }
    }
```

This is the view, I've shortened it a bit by excluding most of the fields. `views/listings/edit.blade.php`

```
{{ Form::model($listings, array('action' => array('ListingsController@getEdit', $listings->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

<div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Overview</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <p>{{ Form::select('status', array(
     ''          => 'Select Status',
     'Active'       => 'Active',
     'Inactive'     => 'Inactive',
     'Trash'     => 'Trash'
      ), null,
      array('class' => 'form-control'
      )) }}
  </p>
{{ Form::submit('Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

From the terminal `php artisan routes`

```
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                             | Name | Action                           | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD users/register/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |      | UsersController@getRegister      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}     |      | UsersController@getLogin         |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/logout/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}    |      | UsersController@getLogout        |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/dashboard/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | UsersController@getDashboard     |                |               |
|        | POST users/create/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}        |      | UsersController@postCreate       |                |               |
|        | POST users/signin/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}        |      | UsersController@postSignin       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE users/{_missing}                 |      | UsersController@missingMethod    |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD listings/main/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}   |      | ListingsController@getMain       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD listings/view/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}   |      | ListingsController@getView       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD listings/add/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}    |      | ListingsController@getAdd        |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD listings/edit/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}   |      | ListingsController@getEdit       |                |               |
|        | POST listings/edit/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}       |      | ListingsController@postEdit      |                |               |
|        | POST listings/add/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}        |      | ListingsController@postAdd       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE listings/{_missing}              |      | ListingsController@missingMethod |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD contacts                                               |      | Closure                          |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE {_missing}                       |      | HomeController@missingMethod     |                |               |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Update Route` is:

```
POST listings/edit/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |  | ListingsController@postEdit
```

So, you should use `postEdit` instead of `getedit` in the `form` action:

```
{{ Form::model($listings, array('action' => array('ListingsController@postEdit', $listings->id))) }}
```

Also `'method' => 'PUT'` should be `'method' => 'POST'` because it should be a `POST` request instead of `PUT` according to your `php artisan routes` results and by default `POST` is used so you may omit it.

Also make sure you have passed the model when you loaded the form from the controller, for example, if you have a method for loading an existing model for editing then you have following route:

```
GET|HEAD listings/edit/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |  | ListingsController@getEdit
```

So, it means, your using `getEdit($id)` to load the model in the form, so you should use something like this:

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
    $listing = Listing::find($id);
    return View::make('listings.edit')->with('listing', $listing);
}
```

In this case the variable name in the `Form::model($listings ... )` should be `$listing` and also `$listing->id` instead of `$listings->id`.

The `getEdit` method should be used to load the form using `GET` request and the `postEdit` method should be used to update the model by submitting the form to a url like `listings/edit/10` using `POST` model.

Comment: I did what you suggested and now I'm getting an error `Undefined variable: listings (View: C:\wamp\www\re3\app\views\listings\edit.blade.php)`

Comment: Most probably you've used `$listing` then use `listing` in stead of `listings`.

Comment: I think it worked, I kept `listings` in `getEdit()` and its now updating the row normally. Although after I click Edit, I get a redirection notice. `HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Sun, 06 Apr 2014 11:12:15 GMT Location: http://localhost/re3/public/listings/main Redirecting to http://localhost/re3/public/listings/main` is that normal? Is there a way to hide the notice?

Comment: So should I keep it `$listings` or make `$listing`? And why do I have to do this?

Comment: If you are using `$listings` in your view then you should send `listings` from controller using `with`.